# Inserting data from a live DB to a test DB (SQL Server 2012)

Tags: sql-server, insert, insert-into

I have a statement I'm trying to run to copy data from a live database to a back-up database, but I am getting the following error:

> Msg 545, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   Explicit value must be specified for identity column in table 'SPRICLIST' either when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to ON or when a replication user is inserting into a NOT FOR REPLICATION identity column.

Can anyone explain to me what this means and if there is a way to circumvent it?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [x3v6].[CICPRODFY].[SPRICLIST] ON

INSERT INTO [x3v6].[CICPRODFY].[SPRICLIST] 
            ([PLI_0]
           ,[PLICRD_0]
           ,[PLILIN_0]
           ,[PLICRI_0]
           ,[PLICRI1_0]
           ,[PLICRI2_0]
           ,[PLICRI3_0]
           ,[PLICRI4_0]
           ,[PLICRI5_0]
           ,[PLISTRDAT_0]
           ,[PLIENDDAT_0]
           ,[CPNITMREF_0]
           ,[UOM_0]
           ,[CUR_0]
           ,[MINQTY_0]
           ,[MAXQTY_0]
           ,[MINAMT_0]
           ,[MAXAMT_0]
           ,[PRIDIV_0]
           ,[PRI_0]
           ,[DCGVAL_0]
           ,[DCGVAL_1]
           ,[DCGVAL_2]
           ,[DCGVAL_3]
           ,[DCGVAL_4]
           ,[DCGVAL_5]
           ,[DCGVAL_6]
           ,[DCGVAL_7]
           ,[DCGVAL_8]
           ,[LTI_0]
           ,[FOCQTYMIN_0]
           ,[FOCQTYBKT_0]
           ,[FOCAMTMIN_0]
           ,[FOCAMTBKT_0]
           ,[FOCITMREF_0]
           ,[FOCUOM_0]
           ,[FOCQTY_0]
           ,[COMCOE_0]
           ,[IMPNUMLIG_0]
           ,[EXPNUM_0]
           ,[CREUSR_0]
           ,[CREDAT_0]
           ,[UPDUSR_0]
           ,[UPDDAT_0])
    SELECT 
        [PLI_0]
           ,[PLICRD_0]
           ,[PLILIN_0]
           ,[PLICRI_0]
           ,[PLICRI1_0]
           ,[PLICRI2_0]
           ,[PLICRI3_0]
           ,[PLICRI4_0]
           ,[PLICRI5_0]
           ,[PLISTRDAT_0]
           ,[PLIENDDAT_0]
           ,[CPNITMREF_0]
           ,[UOM_0]
           ,[CUR_0]
           ,[MINQTY_0]
           ,[MAXQTY_0]
           ,[MINAMT_0]
           ,[MAXAMT_0]
           ,[PRIDIV_0]
           ,[PRI_0]
           ,[DCGVAL_0]
           ,[DCGVAL_1]
           ,[DCGVAL_2]
           ,[DCGVAL_3]
           ,[DCGVAL_4]
           ,[DCGVAL_5]
           ,[DCGVAL_6]
           ,[DCGVAL_7]
           ,[DCGVAL_8]
           ,[LTI_0]
           ,[FOCQTYMIN_0]
           ,[FOCQTYBKT_0]
           ,[FOCAMTMIN_0]
           ,[FOCAMTBKT_0]
           ,[FOCITMREF_0]
           ,[FOCUOM_0]
           ,[FOCQTY_0]
           ,[COMCOE_0]
           ,[IMPNUMLIG_0]
           ,[EXPNUM_0]
           ,[CREUSR_0]
           ,[CREDAT_0]
           ,[UPDUSR_0]
           ,[UPDDAT_0]
      FROM
          [x3v6].[CICPROD].[SPRICLIST]

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [x3v6].[CICPRODFY].[SPRICLIST] OFF
```

Comment: I don't understand what's unclear about the error message.  It's *extremely* specific and clear what the problem is and how to fix it...  You aren't inserting your primary key for that table, and with `IDENTITY INSERT ON` you need to.  Either supply the primary key, or don't use `IDENTITY INSERT`.

Comment: Right, I get that it's a uniqueness issue, but how would I get this to fire? When I try without the IDENTITY INSERT I get the same message. Would I have to create another column and increment that column by 1 or somethng along those lines?